# How to keep adding values to a List using a JButton and JTextArea without them being re-written

Tags: java, netbeans

```
private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    String newCD = (cdInput.getText());


    List <String> cdList = new ArrayList();
    Collections.addAll(cdList, "ExampleG","ExampleB","ExampleR","ExampleX");
    cdList.add(""+newCD);

    List<String> sorted = new ArrayList<String>(cdList);
    Collections.sort(sorted);

    bigBox.setText("");

    bigBox.append("Original Order\n**************\n");

    for (String o : cdList)  {
        bigBox.append(o);
        bigBox.append("\n");
    }

    bigBox.append("\n\nSorted Order\n************\n");

    for (String s : sorted)  {
        bigBox.append(s);
        bigBox.append("\n");
    }
}
```

With this code, I can add 1 value, but when I try to add another one, it erases the original and replaces it. What can I do to prevent this?

PS. I'm trying to make a List of CDs, and be able to add new ones and have them also sorted and put in thier original order

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code, you have no centralised instance of `List`, which means, each time you activate the button, it has no concept of what was previously in the list.

Start by creating an instance variable of the cd `List` and only add new items to it as required.

Something more like...

```
private List<String> cdList = new ArrayList<>(25);

private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    String newCD = (cdInput.getText());
    cdList.add(newCD);

    List<String> sorted = new ArrayList<String>(cdList);
    Collections.sort(sorted);

    bigBox.append("Original Order\n**************\n");

    for (String o : cdList)  {
        bigBox.append(o);
        bigBox.append("\n");
    }

    bigBox.append("\n\nSorted Order\n************\n");

    for (String s : sorted)  {
        bigBox.append(s);
        bigBox.append("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: okay I'm new at programming. How do I create an instance variable of the cdList?

Comment: See the first line of the example code?  That's an instance variable.  It will be accessible to your whole class.  Take a look at [Understanding Instance and Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Comment: The code you just wrote down is kinda working, it's deleting ALL the text and replacing it with the new input though

Comment: Assuming you want to keep the text each time, you need to remove the `bigBix.setText("");` line

Comment: I don't see that line in there

Comment: That came from you original code, I took it out of the example after you last comment ;)

Comment: Okay so I kept my original code, but deleted the bigBox.setText(""); line, and it does nothing

Comment: What do you mean by "does nothing".  Whose original code?  Yours or mine?  Did you make use of instance variable?

Comment: Sorry I'm really new to programming and this freakin code has taken me literally 12 hours to write and it's due tomorrow night. I have an initialize button. It adds 5 CDs to he list and outputs them properly. I am supposed to have an add button (the one we;re working with) hat can add values to that, as many as I'd like, and have them be organized. My problem with my original code is that it erases the newest cd

Comment: Make sure you are only using the instance variable `List` and not creating new local ones

Comment: I'm so new that idk what that means. What would you delete/add to my code?

Comment: From sounds of it.  You have more than one `List` of CD's.  You need to make sure you are only ever interacting with the single, class instance, variable.

Comment: All references to any other cd list and replace them with the single instance level variable